# Possible to set equal height for divs in pairs but only if browser width 960 or wider?

Tags: html, css, javascript, jquery

I'm working on a responsive site where I've found that I've got pairs of divs with heights that I would like to be equal, but only if the browser width is equal to or greater than 960px. Any smaller than that and the divs stack so different heights do not make a difference.

```
DIV 1 | DIV 2
DIV 3 | DIV 4
DIV 5 | DIV 6
DIV 7 | DIV 8
```

Based on the above set up, Div 1 and Div 2 need to be equal height as do Div 3 and Div 4, but both pairs do not need to be equal to each other. i.e. the pair sets can have different heights but each pair must be equal.

Is this possible and if so what is the best approach to take? My javascript/jQuery is rather elementary. I'm sure I could do equal heights alone, but with the pair sets I'm not sure and then adding in the need to set this to only happen if the browser is 960 or wider and I'm lost.

Comment: have you tried something already?

Comment: No I haven't - wasn't sure exactly where to begin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To target the browser width, use a CSS3 media query. There are a couple ways to do this...

In your existing CSS file:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 960px) {
/* css rules for those divs go here */
}
```

Or, setup a new stylesheet and call it like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 960px)" href="big-screen.css" />
```

As for getting equal height divs, there are some methods here: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/  There's also a jQuery method here: http://www.broken-links.com/2009/01/20/very-quick-equal-height-columns-in-jquery/

But I think the trick is having a class already set on those divs so that you can target them with a combination of CSS & jQuery. If it's static code, that should be easy enough. If it's dynamically generated, it'll depend on the output.

Comment: each div is dynamically generated and length is determined by the content added from the client.

Comment: Hm, that makes things tougher. I think you're going to need jQuery to grab the tallest div in each div pair and then set that height for both. Maybe this will help? http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Thank you, your answer got me thinking and then googling. Found the solution here: http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/